# Simplify paths when a user builds

Tags: 2d, javascript, grid, path

I am looking for some guidance on how to simplify my nodes on a path when a user builds on the fly.

Imagine a path like this with a gap:

[image]

Logically 3 nodes are required 2 connected one isolated.

But now the user builds another inbetween these nodes like this:

[image]

You can see the idea is now the nodes have simplified automatically and i only now have 2 nodes on my path.

My question is how would i approach the logic for this so the code can update accordingly? I currently store my path data as an array of nodes which have a property that lists an array of other nodes that link to them. This is what it would look like before the user adds a new tile to the map:

```
var path    = [];
    path[0] = {'x':1,'y':3,'linksTo':[1],'id':0};
    path[1] = {'x':1,'y':4,'linksTo':[0],'id':1};
    path[2] = {'x':1,'y':1,'linksTo':[3] ,'id':2};
    path[2] = {'x':1,'y':0,'linksTo':[2] ,'id':3};
```

I use JavaScript - but the language isn't strictly important only the logical approach here.

I should be more clear, the paths can go in 8 compass directions in total the diagonals will be 45 degree angles rather than any other type of shallow angle. But the image just merely shows an example of a path running north to south.

Comment: Is your path always discrete and always from point to point? (what if there was a path add in bottom image in the middle of bar?)

Comment: @wondra paths can cross over and they would simply create intersections like roads.

Comment: In that case, is on the crossroads new node added?

Comment: @wondra yes any corner or intersection is a node.

Comment: Your question has undefined behavior: at top image how do you know it is not path NE-SW oriented? As for solution, take a look at sweeping algorithms or range trees.

Comment: I don't see how it can be considered NE-SW =/ It's going vertically up and down not 45 degrees top right to bottom left.

Comment: Direction of path with only single point is undecidable.

Comment: If the x is the same and y is changing, thats a pretty good indicator to me that its a north and south direction.....I'm not sure why there is confusion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use two rules, one for tiles and one for corners of tiles:

1. If a floor tile is surrounded by *three* wall tiles and *one* floor tile, then that floor tile is an end of of a corridor, and should be marked with a waypoint.
2. If a corner is surrounded by *one* wall tile and *three* floor tiles, then that corner is a place where you might want to make a turn. The floor tile *opposite* the wall tile should be marked with a waypoint.

I've implemented the second rule with an interactive demo on [this page](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/grids/algorithms.html). Try clicking on the Waypoints diagram and see what waypoints it calculates. I haven't implemented the first rule because it's for single-tile-wide corridors and I didn't have that in the demo.

The second part is to link the waypoints together. Line of sight would work for this; there might be better ways.

Comment: Oh man i love your website i've used it so many times! you really need to come say hi in the game dev chat some time! I'm a bit confused by the wall comments given that i don't have walls on my map just paths (think more like roads than free tiles surrounded by walls)

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would store paths as an array of points/vectors/ whatever they call it in the framework you're using. It's a coordinate, using x and y variables.

When the player builds a path, you know the x and y coordinates of that point (let's call them points). For all your path arrays, check if it contains one of the 8 adjecant points (same x, but y+1, etc). If it contains one of them, it's connected. Now you can go from the point at index 0 in the array, and iterate through them. Check if the angle between A and B is identical to the angle between B and C. If so, remove B from the array (and shift everything down by 1 position in the array). just keep going until you reach the end of the array. All useless nodes have been erased. The only problem here is with intersections. But you could treat them as different paths that simply contain the same point in the array) the intersecting point.